# Dynamic template rendering with Pug Template Engine in Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, pug, mustache

I'm working on a chat app in Node.js, I'm using Pug Template Engine, I got stuck when I tried to render a reusable template, something I achieved with Mustache Template Engine.

**Below is the example of what I'd like to achieve with Pug, Mustache is used in this example**

```
//index.js
  socket.on('newMessage', message => {
  let template = jQuery('#message-template').html();
  let html = Mustache.render(template, {
    text: message.text,
    from: message.from
  });

  jQuery('#messages').append(html)
});
```

**A fragment of my index.html file outputting the result**

```
<div class="chat__main">
    <ol id="messages" class="chat__messages"></ol>

    <div class="chat__footer">
        <form action="" id="message-form">
            <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message" autofocus autocomplete="off">
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <button id="send-location">Send location</button>
    </div>

    <script id="message-template" type="text/template">
        <p>{{text}}</p>
    </script>


</div>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/libs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/libs/moment.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/libs/mustache.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Whatever the user input in the form is dynamically displayed, my question is, how can I achieve this using Pug Template Engine, because I'd like to maintain a Template Engine across my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pug.compileFileClient](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#pugcompilefileclientpath-options%20pug.compileFileClient), you might want to do the `compile` step in an automated way (`gulp`, `grunt`, ...)

> Compile a Pug template file to a string of JavaScript that can be used client side along with the Pug runtime.
>
> First, our template file.
>
> ```
> h1 This is a Pug template
> h2 By #{author}
> ```
>
> Then, we compile the Pug file into a function string.
>
> ```
> var fs = require('fs');
> var pug = require('pug');
>
> // Compile the template to a function string
> var jsFunctionString = pug.compileFileClient('/path/to/pugFile.pug', {name: "fancyTemplateFun"});
>
> // Maybe you want to compile all of your templates to a templates.js file and serve it to the client
> fs.writeFileSync("templates.js", jsFunctionString);
> ```
>
> Here’s what the output function string looks like (written to
>   templates.js).
>
> ```
> function fancyTemplateFun(locals) {
>   var buf = [];
>   var pug_mixins = {};
>   var pug_interp;
>
>   var locals_for_with = (locals || {});
>
>   (function (author) {
>     buf.push("<h1>This is a Pug template</h1><h2>By "
>       + (pug.escape((pug_interp = author) == null ? '' : pug_interp))
>       + "</h2>");
>   }.call(this, "author" in locals_for_with ?
>     locals_for_with.author : typeof author !== "undefined" ?
>       author : undefined)
>   );
>
>   return buf.join("");
> }
> ```
>
> Be sure to send the Pug runtime (node_modules/pug/runtime.js) to the
>   client in addition to the template that you just compiled.
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <script src="/runtime.js"></script>
>     <script src="/templates.js"></script>
>   </head>
>
>   <body>
>     <h1>This is one fancy template.</h1>
>
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>       var html = window.fancyTemplateFun({author: "enlore"});
>       var div = document.createElement("div");
>       div.innerHTML = html;
>       document.body.appendChild(div);
>     </script>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```